# Using String for VertexId graphX

Tags: apache-spark, spark-graphx

I am new to Spark and GraphX. I am trying to create a graph using graphX. However **IDs** in the data are like below:

```
'20|pending_org_::a5055a7d50b4c9777f62181c6fd043bc'
```

As I understood, **VertexId** must be of type **Long** in GraphX but this type of String is not convertible to Long. I need this ID for future steps so I must have it in the graph nodes. Also, I don't want to use fake IDs as data is already big enough.

Any idea how it is possible to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a collision-resistant hash function (for example see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MurmurHash) that produces a 64-bit output (or truncate the first 64 bits if your data doesn't have high cardinallity).